# Find fourth side of quadrilateral given three sides and two angles

Tags: trigonometry, quadrilateral

To completely determine a quadrilateral, you have to have five independent pieces of information, of sides and angles.

If you have five data (all outer sides and a diagonal), finding the angles is easy with the cosine rule.

Similarly with four sides and an angle, the cosine rule is enough to solve for the other angles.

With three sides and two angles, simple application of the cosine rule is enough to find the other sides and angles.

Except in one case. If the two angles are not in between any of the three sides, then there is no immediate way to use the cosine rule. How would the final side be solved for in this case?

Example (apologies for bad quality):[image: Example quadrilateral]

Comment: here is a tedious way - assume one of the angle being $\theta$, then the other is $180^\circ - \theta$. That gives you both diagonals in terms of $\theta$. Now apply cosine rule twice (using one diagonal and then other) to find missing side in terms of $\theta$ and equate. I think that should do it.

Comment: @MathLover $180^\circ-\theta$? The interior angles sum to $360^\circ$ and we have $87+85+\theta+\theta_2=360\implies \theta_2=188-\theta$ as far as I can tell

Comment: I agree with the instinct of  @MathLover, and the correction of FShrike. Math Lover's general approach may be much better than how I would have approached it: I would create the three variables $\alpha, \beta$ (missing angles) and $r$ (missing side).  Then, for each of the two diagonals, I would compute the diagonal in two different ways, using the cosine rule with first 2 sides and one angle, then the opposite sides and opposite angle.  Therefore, I would end up with 2 equations in the three unknowns, based on the diagonals, and a third equation based on the comment of FShrike.

Comment: @FShrike I meant $188^\circ - \theta$, mistyped

Comment: This is how I thought about it first, but the equations became quite horrific. I knew there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the figure such that the side with two angles lies on the $x$-axis, with length $k$. Finding the coordinates of the points, the opposite side must have length $5$, or:

$$(2 \sin 87 - 4 \sin 85)^2 + (k - 2 \cos 87 - 4 \cos 85)^2 = 25 $$
$$\implies k^2 +2(-2 \cos 87-4 \cos85)k + \left((-2 \cos87-4\cos85)^2 + (2 \sin 87 - 4 \sin 85)^2 - 25\right) = 0$$
$$\implies k \approx 5.041$$

---

The constant term can be simplified further as $4 + 16 + 8 \cos 87 \cos 85 - 8 \sin 87 \sin 85 - 25$ $ = 16 \cos 172 - 5$. This gives:

$$k = \frac{4(\cos 87 + 2 \cos 85) + \sqrt{16(\cos 87 + 2 \cos 85)^2 - 4(16 \cos 172 - 5)}}{2}$$

$$= 2(\cos 87 + 2 \cos 85) + \sqrt{4(\cos 87 + 2 \cos 85)^2 - 16 \cos 172  + 5}$$

Comment: The other solution is when $k$ is negative, but $(4 \cos 85, 4 \sin 85)$ will form an obtuse angle with the $x$-axis, so there is only one solution for $k$.

Comment: We can simplify the constant term to $16\cos172°-5$. Several trigonometric functions may be combined using the formulae $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y -\sin x \sin y$.